# Mvvm: How to update my ObservableCollection<customobject> from another ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I am having difficulty in understanding how to update ObservableCollection in ViewModel2 which was defined in ViewModel1. I have searched a lot about how to do this but couldn't get a proper understanding. I am using MVVM Light framework.

I have a DozentViewModel which has an ObservableCollection of Dozents. 
I have another AddDozentViewModel which is used to add new Dozent to the database through Entity Framework. But how do I add the new Dozent to my ObservableCollection in the DozentViewModel?

This is my DozentViewModel:

```
public class DozentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private IDozentDB _dozentDB;
    private ObservableCollection<Dozent> _dozentList;
    private string _nachName;
    private string _vorName;
    private string _akadGrad;

    public RelayCommand ShowAddDozentCommand { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Dozent> DozentList
    {
        get { return _dozentList; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _dozentList, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("DozentList");
        }

    }

    public DozentViewModel(IDozentDB dozentDB)
    {

        _dozentDB = dozentDB;
        DozentList = new ObservableCollection<Dozent>();

        // To get list of all Dozents  
        DozentList = _dozentDB.GetAllDozents();

        ShowAddDozentCommand = new RelayCommand(ShowAddDozentViewExecute);

    }
```

I have bound the DozentList property to my DozentView :

`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DozentList,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Column="0" >`

This is my AddDozentViewModel which adds new Dozent to my SQL database.

```
public AddDozentViewModel(IDozentDB dozentDB)
    {
        _dozentDB = dozentDB;

        // To Add Dozent details to Dozent DB 
        AddCommand = new RelayCommand(AddDozent, CanAddDozent);

     }
    public string NachName
    {
        get { return _nachName; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _nachName, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("NachName");
            AddCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public string VorName
    {
        get { return _vorName; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _vorName, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("VorName");
            AddCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public string AkadGrad
    {
        get { return _akadGrad; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _akadGrad, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("AkadGrad");
            AddCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

        }
    }
    private void AddDozent()
    {
        Dozent dozent = new Dozent();
        dozent.DozentNachname = this.NachName;
        dozent.DozentVorname = this.VorName;
        dozent.AkadGrad = this.AkadGrad;

        _dozentDB.Create(dozent);



        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("CloseAddDozentView"));
    }

    private bool CanAddDozent()
    {
        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NachName)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(VorName)) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AkadGrad));
    }

}
```

I understand that I am just adding the new Dozent to the database and not updating the ObservableCollection. Hence my DataGridView on DozentView does not get updated. How do i do this? Any information would be greatly helpful!!

Thanks,
Vinitha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd look to do here is something along the lines of making `AddDozentViewModel` a property of `DozentViewModel`, which would contain a reference to its parent, e.g.:

```
public class AddDozentViewModel
{
    private readonly DozentViewModel _parent;

    ...

    public AddDozentViewModel(DozentViewModel parent, IDozentDB dozentDB)
    {
        _parent = parent;
        _dozentDB = dozentDB;
    }

    ...

    private void AddDozent()
    {
        Dozent dozent = new Dozent();
        dozent.DozentNachname = this.NachName;
        dozent.DozentVorname = this.VorName;
        dozent.AkadGrad = this.AkadGrad;

        _dozentDB.Create(dozent);

        _parent.DozentList.Add(dozent);

        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("CloseAddDozentView"));

        _parent.AddDozentViewModel = null; // this will dispose of the AddDozentViewModel
    }

    ...
}
```

The `DozentViewModel` would therefore look something like this:

```
public class DozentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...

    private AddDozentViewModel _addDozentViewModel;
    public AddDozentViewModel AddDozentViewModel
    {
        get { return _addDozentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            Set(ref _addDozentViewModel, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged("_addDozentViewModel");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Also, to be extra certain the new `Dozent` had been written to the database, and so I always feel like I'm synced with the database, I'd perhaps look into retrieving the new `Dozent` from the database before adding it to `DozentList`. So that would alter the `AddDozent()` method to something like:

```
private void AddDozent()
{
    Dozent dozent = new Dozent();
    dozent.DozentNachname = this.NachName;
    dozent.DozentVorname = this.VorName;
    dozent.AkadGrad = this.AkadGrad;

    _dozentDB.Create(dozent);

    Dozent newDozentFromDB = // retrieve it from _dozentDB here

    _parent.DozentList.Add(newDozentFromDB);

    Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("CloseAddDozentView"));

    _parent.AddDozentViewModel = null; // this will dispose of the AddDozentViewModel
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification.

Comment: It worked !! :) I have a trivial doubt. I liked the idea of retrieving newly added Dozent from database and add it to my ObservableCollection. Doing so, I am retreiving the dozent with its Id like so : `Dozent newDozentFromDB = _dozentDB.GetDozent(dozent.DozentId);` . I hope I am retreiving the dozent with the correct dozent ID? Anyways, it works and I am able to view to updated Collection in the datagrid.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't too sure on how you were working the database, so I left the specifics of that out, but any way of identifying your distinct `Dozent` is fine. You could even refactor this into a method that accepts a `Dozent`, adds it to the database, and returns a `Dozent` for you to add to the collection..

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVMLight's `Messenger` for viewmodel communication.

for example:

```
public class AddDozentViewModel
{
    //... 

    private void AddDozent()
    {
        Dozent dozent = new Dozent();
        //...

        Messenger.Default.Send(new NewDozentAddedMessage(dozent));
    }
}

public class DozentViewModel
{
    //...

    private ObservableCollection<Dozent> _dozentList;
    public DozentViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NewDozentAddedMessage>(this, HandleNewDozentAddedMessage);
    }
    private void HandleNewDozentAddedMessage(NewDozentAddedMessage obj)
    {
        _dozentList.Add(obj.DozentObject);
    }
}

public class NewDozentAddedMessage
{
    public Dozent DozentObject { get; }
    public NewDozentAddedMessage(Dozent dozentObject)
    {
        DozentObject = dozentObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this information!! It really helped.